# How do you clear output buffers when the program forks?

Tags: linux, file-io, fork

I have a program that writes to a FILE *cgiOut and just after it has written to the stream, I need to fork and run a background process.  The trouble is that after the fork, the FILE * stream seems to flush out sometimes and I get duplicated output (after the fork, all open files are closed which I guess causes the buffers to be flushed).  How can I avoid this?  I don't want to close the file in the master process as it is opened in a library and it is a socket or pipe I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite sure I understand your question, but if you want to make sure your `cgiOut` buffers are empty before you `fork()` you can use `fflush()` on the stream just before you `fork()`. That should force the buffers to be flushed.

It maybe suitable to use an unbuffered stream, by changing the buffering settings via `setvbuf()` and friends. This way you won't (read: shouldn't) have any buffering issues, but it might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

[`fflush(file)`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/fflush.html)